# "400 no matchind index found" Datastore Entity and google firestore

Tags: python, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

I am using code sampled in the [Datastore Entity docs](https://datastore-entity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I don't see a reason why it is not being able to index and find what I am looking for.

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db
from flask_login import UserMixin
from datastore_entity import DatastoreEntity, EntityValue
import os
import datetime

class User(DatastoreEntity, UserMixin):
    username = EntityValue(None)
    status = EntityValue(1)
    date_created = EntityValue(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
    __kind__ = "user"

    def get(self, value):
        return self.get_obj('username',value)

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="serviceAccountKey.json"

user = User()
user.username = 'komla'
user.save()


user = User().get('komla')
```

This is very basic straight from documents, but it is still unable to find the username with komla, so I receive this error.

```
google.api_core.exceptions.FailedPrecondition: 400 no matching index found.
```

I am creating a user with the username of komla, then when I try to get the document with that ID it is not able to find it.

(The user is successfully created in cloud firestore)

Comment: - In Datastore mode, you're able to view the index both in production and dev and you would normally get this error (in production) when the index file is still being built or the local version wasn't uploaded to production. I don't know if the behavior is the same for Firestore. So, check if there's a menu for index in production. If it's there, check if it's empty or showing something like - `building index'

Answer (score 0):

Your code is confusing the two APIs of Cloud Firestore.  Cloud Firestore supports both the Firestore native API & the Cloud Datastore API.  However, the indexing expectations are different between the modes.  So if you set up a database as Cloud Firestore in native mode, then queries using the Cloud Datastore API will return no index found errors.

Your choices today (2022-03-06) are to: (1) use the Firestore client libraries only with your Cloud Firestore database in native more, or (2) switch your database to Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode and use the Datastore client libraries.